# Is static variable really safe to exchange data between activities?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm working on an application that consist of a couple of activities:

- Activity 1: main screen of an application with a "Start" button
- Activity 2: user selects its identity from the list (more than one user is going to use the application)
- Activity 3: user inputs password
- Activity 4: user chooses an event from a timetable (every user has its own timetable with associated events)
- Activity 5: user can choose an action connected with an activity.
- Activities 6-10: user performs appropriate action.

Below some more information:

- every activity from 6-10 have to know what user is logged in and what event has been selected
- every activity from 6-10 has a menu that allows the user to go back to activities: 1 (to log out), 4 (to select different event), 5 (to select different action)

Since now, I've been using bundles to exchange data between activities but it seems to complicate the code as the number of actions grow (some actions use a 3-4 activities to collect data from the user). Passing all the data to every created activity doesn't seems to be nice.

I'm thinking about storing the "user name" and selected "event" as a static fields of a class. I will simplify the code very much, but I'm not sure whether this data will persist if the user let say at some point press "home button" and run another application that needs a lot of memory.

Will the data stored in static fields be safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You are not guaranteed that these will all exist in the same classloader, in which case you would be dealing with different copies of these classes in different places, and not accessing the same shared state.

It may happen to work now; but no it is not something I would call "safe".

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same classloader"? I thought there is only one copy of the class available to the whole application.

Comment: No, two different `Activity` instances are not guaranteed to be in the same `ClassLoader`. They would have two copies then. Also, within one `Activity`, the `Class` may change over time: the OS is free to unload your app in `onDestroy()`, and create a new `ClassLoader` and re-load it.

Comment: What would happen if I store my vairables in a class which extends Application? Will it be better than "static"?

Answer (score 5):

It's better to have a custom Application object and store them there. The application object will live aslong as your app does.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

You can get access to the Application object by casting getApplicationContext() to whatever your custom Application type is:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private String userId;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    ...
}
```

From Activity call: `((CustomApplication) getApplicationContext()).getUserId();`

Comment: seems to be a good solution, but what if the system will kill my app (for example if the memory will be needed for another app)? After going back to my app, will my app start from the very beginning or will the system just launch the latest activity?

Comment: If you're also persisting the data then I suggest you properly create a design for your app before touching **any** code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the SharedPreference for this instead of using static variable/object into the class. check out this blog http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

Comment: Try storing a complex object in a SharedPreference.

Comment: isn't SharedPreferences designed to store persistent data?

Comment: check this post for using static variable http://stackoverflow.com/q/7763864/760489

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the intent system as designed. Statics and Activities can get killed seemingly willy-nilly by Android. Even the Application class can get killed.

Say your have an app consisting of two activities, the first one lets the user store some data in the Application object. The user then clicks a button to start the second activity which displays the data. The user puts their phone down and comes back to it several hours later.

Android might decide to kill the app for various reasons during this time. When the user comes back, picks up the phone and relaunches your app a new Application object will be created and the second activity will be restored but the data the user entered will no longer be available in the Application object because it is a new Application object.

One way to help with this is to use SharedPreferences even for complex objects. Gson is perfectly capable of serializing and deserializing them to SharedPreferences.

To simulate this you can do the following:

$adb shell ps | grep your.app.package

to get the pid of your running app, then

$ adb shell kill -9

then open the app with the task switcher and you will have a new Application object but will be on the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields work but not graceful. You just need a session object following singleton pattern.

Comment: actually, i believe singletons can get killed at any time, and it's not very safe to do so. this can introduce a TON of weird errors, and it's very very difficult to track down

Answer (score 0):

Static data will persist on pressing home button and on opening your application again you will go to the same state where you left but when you run another application which needs lot of memory there are possibilities that you may lost your all static data.
But if you have very less static data then it may persist.

You can also look for SharedPreference.

Comment: What about when you store your variables in a class extending Application? Is there a possibility of losing this data when another application needs a lot of memory?

Answer (score -1):

You can Use the static unless and untill you are sure that this static variable will not conflict the users.
also static variable are class's property so it consumes more memory because lifetime is application level.
other i can suggest is to use shared prefereces which very handy. this shared preferences can be access by any of the activity of your application. so no need to pass bundle and worry about static fields.
last option is which is i dont find importance in your application is "Use Database to store and retreive".

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Hasan Khan hey sorry i was typing actually. i think now my ans is fine.